# Get html element from my own web page from a WebView?

Tags: android

I have a webview displaying a page from my own server. Is it possible to add a javascript method that would allow my android app to read out a page element from the webview? Something like:

```
// mypage.html
<html>
   <p id='abc'>some data</p>
</html>

// my android app
WebView wv = ..;
String data = wv.getPageElementById('abc');
```

Anything like that? I own the page so I can modify it however I need to make it work,

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok this is how i did it:

```
<html>

  <head> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

      function onBodyLoad() {
        var element = document.getElementById("abc");
        window.javascriptAccessor.getYerData(element.innerHTML); 
      }

    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body onload="onBodyLoad()">
    <div id="abc">data</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then my activity:

```
WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.addJavascriptInterface(new JavascriptAccessor(), "javascriptAccessor");
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {}); // wouldn't work without this!
webview.loadUrl(url);

private class JavascriptAccessor {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void getYerData(String data) {
        Log.v(TAG, data);
    }
}
```

Yeah!