# Android WebView: get html div from website

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview

I want to get div data from website with webview. Sorry for my bad English. Thanks.

my website code

```
<html>
    <div id="test">get this data</div>
</html>
```

my mainactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String url = "http://website.com";
        WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a `HTTP GET` request to your sever using an `AsyncTask`, then once you can the page's data (html) as a string parse it and extract from it your wanted content using `RegEx group`.
And now you can load the content in your `webview` using `webView.loadData(htmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8")`

Comment: I want to get data in webview because I have login system. I want to get username if user is loggin to my site.

Comment: @brave, I've updated my answer, kindly check it and let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am doing this in two steps: the Native code sends request to the JS part, then JS sends back data to the Native.
For this you have to organize some JS interface in the Native and add it to your "onCreate". Not very complicated. This is the code:
JS interface:

```
 public class JavaScriptInterface {
        Context mContext;        
        private GoogleApiClient client;            
        public JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void getDataFromJs(String divData){
            //here is your code
        }
}
```

Now you can add it to "onCreate" like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  public static WebView view;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String url = "http://website.com";
    view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    view.getSettings().setBlockNetworkImage(false);
    view.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    view.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    view.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);              
    view.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");

    view.loadUrl(url);
  }
}
```

Here we gave a name of Android to the JavaScriptInterface.
Then in Native would be logical to add some function sending request (or data) to the JS (you have to add it to the MainActivity class just after the "onCreate"):

```
public static String sendToJS(final String inStr, final String address) {
    final String sendStr = String.format("javascript:%s('%s')", address, inStr.toString());
    String response = "";
    try {
         view.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                view.loadUrl(sendStr);
            }
        });
        response = sendStr;
    }catch(Exception e){
        response = e.getMessage();
    }
    return response;
}
```

And in JS the addressed function:

```
function myFunction(inData){
   //your code cares about inData if you need it
   var outData = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;
   Android.getDataFromJs(outData );
}
```

And finally usage (from the Native):

```
sendToJS("yourStringData", "myFunction");
```

The answer your are getting in the JavaScriptInterface in the "getDataFromJs" method.
Is it helpful for you?

Comment: Thank you @LeonidZ Can you add your code to my code? because I don't know android. Thanks.

Comment: and I saw this post but not work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034948/get-html-element-from-my-own-web-page-from-a-webview

Comment: Hi @LeonidZ Does your code get data from webviev? I want to get data in webview because I have login system. I want to get username if user is loggin to my site

Comment: Well, now I've inserted my code into your code. In addition, I  added

Comment: Well, now I've inserted my code into your code. In addition you can see there optional permissions.

Comment: About your question on login system - yes, it might be and it is working as login system. Try the current code. It should work.

Comment: I couldnt do it. I don't use native I use only webview. I'm sorry to bother you. I'm newbie